# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django

I am getting the error below:

```bash
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I don't know where to look

Comment: Did you activate your virtual env?

Comment: in app urls.py, app_name = <app_name> parameter. If you created new app, you need to add it at last of the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not deleted the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py`. Something similar to:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # add new apps here and don't delete the ones above
]
``
```